# How to redirect users to their own profile page?

Tags: php, mysql, user-profile

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_reg ");  
?>
```

The issue I am having is that I have a link in the navigation bar called 'User Profile'. This link should fetch a list of all the current users in the database but i only need personal profile of login user.

Comment: Do you have the users id from the session or a parameter? Can that be used in your query or to go to a url?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would recommend reading [this article on asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

As to your question, I assume you have already implemented a login system for your users. If so, you should have the user's id in a `$_SESSION` variable or a `$_COOKIE` variable. There is much documentation on accessing these variables on the PHP website. You can use this `id` to get the right user on the profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL query so that it only selects the profile of a certain user. For example if you know the user's email and it is stored in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM p_reg WHERE email='userEmailAddress@email.com'
```